# How to set the width of TableRow on Andorid (programmatically)

Tags: java, android, tablerow, programmatically-created

i have table with 3 columns. I need set first and third column to fixed size (like 150px). But second column must fill all the remaining space

I use this code, but it's not work.

```
                TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
                tableLayout.setColumnStretchable(1, true);
                tableRow.addView(CurRemButton, new TableRow.LayoutParams(150, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
                tableRow.addView(ItemsName[Items.ItemId], new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f)); 
                tableRow.addView(CurAddButton, new TableRow.LayoutParams(150, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
```

Comment: Google for `android:stretchColumns`

Comment: I need to do this programmatically, instead of XML